# Acute select: ac-options and ac-model attributes must be set in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need `acute select`. I have referred this [enter link description here](https://github.com/john-oc/acute-select"Link")

Am getting error in console after adding all these dependencies

**MainPage.html**

```
<ac-select ac-model='hospitalData.hospitalName' 
 ac-options='hospital.hospitalName as hospital.hospitalName for hospital in hospNameList' 
 ac-change='selectionChanged(value)' 
 ac-settings='{ loadOnOpen: true }'></ac-select>
```

> Error

```
ac-options and ac-model attributes must be set <ac-select ac-model="hospitalData.hospitalName" ac-options="hospital.hospitalName as hospital.hospitalName for hospital in hospNameList" ac-change="selectionChanged(value)" ac-settings="{ loadOnOpen: true }" class="ng-isolate-scope">
```

**Controller.js**

```
scope.hospitalData=null;
scope.hospitalData.hospitalName=null;
scope.hospNameList=null;
//added above after refferring issue on github,But still not working    

gethospNameList();
function gethospNameList() {
    Repository.gethospNameList().then(
    function(result) {
      scope.hospNameList = result;
      console.log("hospNameList :"+ scope.hospNameList);
    });
};
```

Comment: exactly what scenario you need..because acute select is no longer active

Comment: @Sravan I need to display dropdown content from DB. With tht provide user a option to enter within the textBox. If content is present in dropdown user can select. Else whtever user types should bind to model As i need tht for server side

Comment: acute select has a combomode for it.. but it is no longer working.. you can try `angular-ui-select`

Comment: @Sravan Yeah tried but facing some issue, Any example would be helpful..

Comment: ok, let me create one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution using `angular-ui-select`

**The below is just a snippet**

**Check the plunger for working code:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.select']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.superhero = {
      selected: 'Sravan'
    };
       
    $scope.getSuperheroes = function(search) {
     var newSupes = $scope.superheroes.slice();
      if (search && newSupes.indexOf(search) === -1) {
        newSupes.unshift(search);
      }
      return newSupes;
    }
    
    $scope.superheroes = [
      'Sravan',
      'Hema',
      'AnotherUser',
        
    ];
});
```

```html
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.css">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.8.5/css/selectize.default.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="select.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <ui-select ng-model="superhero.selected">
                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a superhero ...">{{$select.selected}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="hero in getSuperheroes($select.search) | filter: $select.search">
                  <div ng-bind="hero"></div>
                </ui-select-choices>
              </ui-select>
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">You have chosen {{ superhero.selected }}!</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

[Here is a working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KER6aJbcwNUTC4iVjkTO?p=preview)