# Showing choice on no result in ui-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-select

I am using `ui-select` in AngularJS to show select options from given values. I want to display a choice when there is no search result. Is there any way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44499460/6756805 you can refer this

Comment: this is showing option of adding asynchronous option, I want to show a predefined option when no result is found

Comment: if ur search is not found. then u want to add new value to ur ng-model right..?

Comment: yes like create new when no search is found

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ui-select-no-choice`. It should be used right after `ui-select-choices`. Refer to official documentation i have included link.

```
<ui-select-no-choice>
  Sorry! No choices found!!
</ui-select-no-choice>
```

Reference : [ui-select-no-choice](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-no-choice)

Comment: Yes, this can be done when we want to show no search found message.

I want to select the new element when no search found, something like create a new when no search found.

Comment: if you requirement is to add new value in case of no value found in existing list, you could use `ui-select-multiple` fot that.